# Can I bundle App_Themes css files with Microsoft.Web.Optimization?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, minify, bundling-and-minification, app-themes

Does anyone know if it is possible to bundle and minify WebForms App_Themes using Microsoft.Web.Optimization?

Answer (score 2):

This could be a possible solution, I did it this way :

> So how do we dynamically register some CSS files in an App_Theme
>   folder without the default files being rendered down to the client?
>   The short answer is, you can't. The long answer is, we can with a bit
>   of a work around.

[Using the Bundling and Minification Web Optimisations with Asp.Net WebForms App_Themes](http://boniestdeveloper.net/post/2012/10/30/Using-the-Bundling-and-Minification-Web-Optimisations-with-AspNet-WebForms-App_Themes.aspx)

Comment: Archived link (original is down): https://web.archive.org/web/20200217000436/https://boniestdeveloper.net/post/2012/10/30/Using-the-Bundling-and-Minification-Web-Optimisations-with-AspNet-WebForms-App_Themes.aspx